Do the spectra of the resolvents for the Dirichlet Laplacian acting in $L^2$ and in $H^1$ coincide?
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain (not necessarily bounded), and let $H$ the Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega)$ equipped with a standard scalar product
$$
(u,v)_\mathcal{H}:= \int_\Omega u\overline{v}dx.
$$
We define the operator $T:H\to H$ as follows:
$f\mapsto u$, where $u$ is the solution to the problem
$$
 \text{Find }u\in H^1_0(\Omega):\ \int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\overline{\nabla v} dx +\int_\Omega u\overline{v}dx=\int_\Omega  u\overline{v}dx,\ \forall v\in H^1(\Omega).\qquad\qquad     (1)
$$
In other words, $u=Tf$ is the unique weak solution to equation
$-\Delta u + u = f$
in $\Omega$ subject to the Dirichlet boundary conditions in $\partial\Omega$.
Now, let $\widetilde H$ be a Hilbert space $H^1(\Omega)$ with a scalar product
$$
(u,v)_{\widetilde H}:=\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\overline{\nabla v} dx +\int_\Omega u\overline{v}dx.
$$
Then we define the operator $\widetilde{T}:\widetilde H\to \widetilde H$ as follows: $\widetilde H\ni f\mapsto u$, where $u$ is the solution to the problem (1). Evidently, $\widetilde{T} f = T f$ for $f\in \widetilde H$.
It is easy to see that $T$ (resp. $\widetilde T$) is bounded and self-adjoint as an operator acting in $H$ (resp. $\widetilde H$).
Now, the question  comes: do the spectra of $T$ and $\widetilde T$ coincide?
It looks that if $\Omega$ is bounded, the spectra indeed coincide (they share the same eigenfunctions). But what about unbounded domains?
